# How to upload only certain formats in image upload in php using pathinfo_extension

Tags: php, image-upload

I have an image upload section in my page. There user should upload only image format. i have created the code with checking file extension with PATHINFO_EXTENSION.

```
if(isset($_POST['addstaff']))
{
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $photo=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
    $phototmp=$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
    $location="staff/";
    $uploading=move_uploaded_file($phototmp,"staff/".$photo);
    $up="staff/".$photo;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($photo,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $empid=$_POST['empid'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $password=password_hash($pass,PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $branch=$_POST['branch'];
    $doj=$_POST['doj'];
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "<script>alert('Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.');</script>";
        }
        else{
            $query="insert into staffdetails value('','$name','$empid','$branch','$doj','$up')";
        $exe=mysqli_query($con,$query);
        if($exe){
            echo "<script>alert('Inserted');</script>";
        }
        else{
            echo "errr".mysqli_error($con);
        }
        }


}
```

Here the problem is when I upload a php file or any other file rather than image files it correctly displays the alert message "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed." But also it inserts the file. I added this in `if else` condition Then how both if and else condition works together. Please anyone help

Comment: You should check the file extension _before_ you call `move_uploaded_file()` (which is the function that actually copies the uploaded file to your upload folder).

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Using prepared statements doesn't prevent SQL injection?

Comment: You _should_ be using parameterized prepared statements since it _does_ prevent SQL injections.

Comment: What is the difference? could you give me any reference

Comment: I did post some links to explain both SQL injections and prepared statements. Start by reading those (start with SQL injections).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call move_uploaded_file() function after validation success

Change code to below

```
if(isset($_POST['addstaff']))
{
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $photo=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
    $phototmp=$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
    $location="staff/";
    $up="staff/".$photo;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($photo,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $empid=$_POST['empid'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $password=password_hash($pass,PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $branch=$_POST['branch'];
    $doj=$_POST['doj'];
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "<script>alert('Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.');</script>";
        }
        else{
            $uploading=move_uploaded_file($phototmp,"staff/".$photo);
            $query="insert into staffdetails value('','$name','$empid','$branch','$doj','$up')";
            $exe=mysqli_query($con,$query);
           if($exe){
               echo "<script>alert('Inserted');</script>";
           }
           else{
               echo "errr".mysqli_error($con);
           }
        }


}
```